# Disable autocomplete hints on iTerm2

Tags: macos, mac, bash, autocomplete, iterm2

I would like to disable the autocomplete [history](/questions/tagged/history) things that come up on the [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com), as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the blue hint that comes up when I start typing a command similar to the one that was previously executed.

Comment: What a hopeless feature that is.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can disable the auto command completion by navigating to the following menu:

`View` `>` `Auto command completion`

Comment: I passed by this so many times trying to find out how to do this 

Comment: This would be a useful feature if I could use [Tab] to get through the suggestions, rather than [Tab] causing a bell and having to use [Enter] to go through the selections. And to have it not be configurable? terrible. They did everything else so well, too!

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me crazy. I was making multiple changes to my iTerm2, and I initially thought it was zsh and oh-my-zsh triggering this. Lesson learned :)

Comment: I think I went through every option in preferences to find this haha. Thank you :)

Comment: I've been looking for this for ages! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, i wish there was an option to delay it so I could keep it, or at least make it optional when it's suggesting me

Comment: Thanks for posting. It's been annoying me for a while. 
It has some use, but I think it should be designed in such a way so that it doesn't interfere with what you're doing. I want to press enter and run my command instead of accidentally triggering a previous command. It also should be smart enough to do predictions perhaps or something that's actually somewhat useful..

Comment: It's so weird, this option is greyed out for me. Anybody got any clue? I searched for hours.